# Somar uma coluna em que seus valores já são resultados de outra soma

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-html, sum

Eu tenho 2 tabelas em um banco de dados, uma contem as ordens de compras, outra contem os itens dessa ordens de compra, esses dados são obtidos de uma importação de outro sistema por isso não tenho chave estrangeira veiculando as tabelas, porém tenho informações que consigo uni-las no select.

Ordens de Compra:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Itens das Ordens de compras:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Obs.: São só alguns dos registros que tenho no banco para usar como exemplo.

O select que faço é este:

```
SELECT sc.empresa, sc.cod_autorizante, sc.codigo_ordem_compra, ( 
    SELECT SUM(ioc.valor_total) as soma 
    FROM itens_ordens_compras ioc 
    WHERE ioc.codigo_empresa = sc.empresa 
    and ioc.cod_ordem_compra = sc.codigo_ordem_compra ) as valor_t 
from solicitacao_compras sc 
where sc.cod_autorizante = 222 
and sc.data_aprovacao like '%/10/2020' 
GROUP by sc.codigo_ordem_compra;
```

Obs. 2: Eu faço com o **GROUP by sc.codigo_ordem_compra** porque sem ele eu tenho registros que acabam se repetindo.

E consigo obter este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta e necessidade é, consigo dar um select próximo a este só que fazendo uma soma da coluna **valor_t** aonde me traria no caso deste exemplo o valor  R$203.034,66, as outras informações não precisariam aparecer, só este valor final mesmo.

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Não tenho experiência com o MySQL, mas se a versão que você estiver utilizando permite o uso de CTE (Common Table Expressions), você pode tentar de forma semelhante a que segue:

```
with CTE_Origem as
(
    -- consulta inicial
)

select sum(soma) as soma from CTE_Origem
```

Se por acaso não for possivel utilizar CTE, você pode tentar com uma tabela derivada:

```
select sum(soma) as soma
from
(
    -- consulta inicial
) as t
```

Edit: exemplo completo com uma tabela derivada:

```
select sum(t.valor_t) as soma
from
(
  SELECT sc.empresa, sc.cod_autorizante, sc.codigo_ordem_compra, ( 
    SELECT SUM(ioc.valor_total) as soma 
    FROM itens_ordens_compras ioc 
    WHERE ioc.codigo_empresa = sc.empresa 
    and ioc.cod_ordem_compra = sc.codigo_ordem_compra) as valor_t 
  from solicitacao_compras sc 
  where sc.cod_autorizante = 222 
  and sc.data_aprovacao like '%/10/2020' 
  GROUP by sc.codigo_ordem_compra
) as t
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Valeu por responder Imex, mas tentei usar a primeira opção e não reconheceu o with. Já a segunda opção sua, é a opção que estou usando no select ali em cima, ela até soma os valores, mais eu precisava que somasse o que já está sendo somado para dar um valor total final dos registros.

Comment: Você deve estar utilizando uma versão antiga que não suporta CTE. Sobre a segunda opção, é diferente do que você usou, que no caso é uma subconsulta. Editei o post para acrescentar um exemplo completo, tente fazer uns testes. Espero que ajude

Comment: Ah tá, agora intendi, sem o exemplo que você colocou, eu estava achando que era a mesma coisa que eu já havia feito, mas agora vi que não é, você colocou mais um select e dentro dele o que eu havia feito, perfeito Imex, me trouxe o resultado certinho, era isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado.